# Algebraic version of Loos Symmetric Space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, symmetric-spaces

Ottmar Loos gave a definition of symmetric spaces in terms of the existence of a multiplication map.  Namely, a manifold $M$ is symmetric if there exists a multiplication morphism $\mu:M\times M\to M$ such that for all $x,y,z\in M$
$$ \mu(x,x)=x$$
$$\mu(x,\mu(x,y))=y$$
$$\mu(\mu(x,y),\mu(x,z))=\mu(x,\mu(y,z))$$
$$\text{For all }x\in M\text{ there is a neighborhood }U\text{ of }x\text{ such that if }y\in U \text{ and } \mu(x,y)=y\text{ then }y=x.$$

He shows these axioms are equivalent to $M$ being a symmetric space in the sense that there exists a Lie group $G$ and an involutive automorphism $\sigma$ of $G$ such that $M\cong G/K$ where $(G^\sigma)^\circ\subseteq K\subseteq G^\sigma$.  His book "Symmetric Spaces I" has all of this information.

My question is whether someone has proven/studied a similar characterization in the algebraic setting?  That is, if $X$ is a variety over an algebraically closed field with a multiplication map satisfying the same axioms, is it true that $X$ is in fact a symmetric space?

Comment: Would you provide a reference for Loos' work?

Comment: @YCor He wrote a bulletin paper here: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183528790.   I also posted in the question the book "Symmetric Spaces I", which has this work in it.

Comment: Shouldn't this be equivalent to a Jordan algebra approach?

Comment: @NicolaCiccoli I don't think so because, as far as I understand, the only Riemannian symmetric spaces that arise from Jordan algebras are the Hermitian symmetric spaces.  But this approach produces all symmetric spaces, not only the Hermitian ones.